# Data retrieving from XElemnt using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XElement as follows

```
<row>
  <field name="field1">Test1</field>
  <field name="field2">Test2</field>
  <field name="field3">Test3</field>
</row>
```

I want to retrieve value Test2 using the attribute value field2 using LINQ.I tried the following code

```
var data= item.Elements("field").Single(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "field2");
```

It's not working.When I run the code it fails with error **Sequence contains no matching element** >

I don't know what I'm missing here.How can I retrieve the value using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. The code should be like this

```
var data = item.Elements().Single(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "field2").Value;
```